# Doesn't support required feature: android.hardware.camera

Tags: android, wear-os, google-play-console

I'm running into an issue where my wear os app is not showing up in the play store to be downloaded. It is available to internal testers, but when released into production the app is not available to outside users. When looking at the device catalog it is telling me that the application is not supported only in the production track for any watch and provides the reason: `Doesn't support required feature: android.hardware.camera`

I have found other solutions that reference the issue to the line: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` in the app manifest suggesting that
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false"/>` should be added. My issue is that I am only requesting camera access in my main application manifest, and there is no reference listed in my wear os manifest. I am also unclear as to why this issue is only prevalent in builds that are in production vs. internal testers.

Screen shot provided showing message:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked manifest in the generated apk? Maybe it was merged with something that has camera requirement